# Facebook like/share doesn't find text on my pages - HTML structure?

Tags: html, facebook, xhtml, facebook-like

I have a page that is being shared on facebook a decent amount:  https://www.sittingaround.com/

However, none of the ways of sharing it on facebook find the text on the page (addthis buttons, stumbleupon toolbar, from facebook).  I expect this is something to do with facebook expecting my HTML to have a certain structure that my site does not have.  I have ruled out HTTPS as the issue by sharing https://github.com which is able to find text.

This problem exists on all of my pages, not just the homepage.

I've looked through a fair amount of the facebook documentation and stack overflow questions, but haven't found a solution.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're required to use the [Open Graph Protocol](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/) to enable facebook crawler to read your page. A simple test could be done with help of [Facebook URL linter](http://developers.facebook.com/tools/lint?url=https://www.sittingaround.com/)

Comment: Thanks. The URL linter helped me figure out why FB was doing this -- long story short my meta description was set to "" (an empty string)